# Spring RequestParam Map<String, String>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myUrl(@RequestParam(value = "test") Map<String, String> test)
{
    return test.toString();
}
```

And I'm making this HTTP request:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/myUrl?test[a]=1&test[b]=2
```

But in the logs I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Map parameter 'test' is not present
```

How can I pass `Map<String, String>` to Spring?

Answer (score 3):

May be it's a bit late but this can be made to work by declaring an intermediate class:

```
public static class AttributeMap {
    private Map<String, String> attrs;

    public Map<String, String> getAttrs() {
        return attrs;
    }

    public void setAttrs(Map<String, String> attrs) {
        this.attrs = attrs;
    }
}
```

And using it as parameter type in method declaration (w/o @RequestParam):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myUrl(AttributeMap test)
```

Then with a request URL like this:
http://localhost:8080/myUrl?attrs[1]=b&attrs[222]=aaa

In test.attrs map all the attributes will present as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It's not immediately clear what you are trying to do since `test[a]` and `test[b]` are completely unrelated query string parameters.

You can simply remove the `value` attribute of `@RequestParam` to have your `Map` parameter contain two entries, like so

```
{test[b]=2, test[a]=1}
```

Comment: The documentation says that the `@RequestParam` should have a parameter name specified, or the map will be populated with all the request parameters: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html and that is indeed what happens. My goal is to have a map with the keys `a` and `b`, and values `1` and `2` respectively.

Comment: @stackular As far as I know, that is not possible by default. You'll need to write and register your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to do that.

Comment: @stackular Are the keys random? If they aren't, just use a command object.

Comment: Yes, the keys are arbitrary ("random").

Comment: @stackular AFAIK you will need then need to write your own logic to convert them to a `Map` (or ideally some wrapper object).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Would you have an example of such a argumentResolver impl?